# Lumen - pagination links() method not working

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I am trying to create a paginated resultset in Lumen. I am not using a database collection, instead it is an array collection.

I have managed to get the results to display, however I am having a problem getting the pagination links() method to work. Here is what I have:

PHP:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;

class AppController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $items = [
            'item1',
            'item2',
            'item3',
            'item4',
        ];

        $collection = collect($items);

        $currentPage = LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage();
        $perPage = 2;
        $offset = ($currentPage * $perPage) - $perPage;

        $currentPageResults = $collection->slice($offset, $perPage)->all();

        $paginatedItems = new LengthAwarePaginator($currentPageResults, count($collection), $perPage);

        $paginatedItems->setPath($request->url());

        return view('index', [
            'results' => $paginatedItems,
        ]);
    }
}
```

View:

```
<ul>
    @foreach ($results as $result)
        <li>{{ $result }}</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>

<div>
    {{ $results->links() }}
</div>
```

The error I am getting is:

> call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, no array
>   or string given

If I remove `$results->links()` I don't get the error.

When I `dd($paginationItems)` I do get back a valid `LengthAwarePaginator` object:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:

Within `bootstrap/app.php` there is a line of code commented out by default:

`// $app->withEloquent();`

This needs to be uncommented for the pagination links() method to work.

Comment: Excelent! Issue solved! Thanks!